# Doctrine ArrayCollection matching criteria function results in Undefined property: MyEntity::$1 (Symfony 3.4)

Tags: doctrine, criteria, symfony-3.4, arraycollection, doctrine-collection

I defined an Entity "TrainingProgressEntry" as an @ORM\Entity and a "training" property like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Training", inversedBy="training_progress")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="training_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $training;
```

The matching @ORM\Entity "Training" defines a property "training_progress" like

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TrainingProgressEntry", mappedBy="training", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"entry_date" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $training_progress;
```

and a getter method for it like this

```
/**
 * Get trainingProgress
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getTrainingProgress()
{
    return $this->training_progress;
}
```

Finaly I define a getter method intended to return only entries which have a date newer then some reference date:

```
/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getTrainingProgressSinceStart()
{
    $startTime = $this->getUser()->getStart();
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->gt('entry_date', $startTime))
        ->orderBy(['entry_date', 'ASC']);
    return $this->getTrainingProgress()->matching($criteria);
}
```

When using this last function I get the following "ContextErrorException":

```
Notice: Undefined property: AppBundle\Entity\TrainingProgressEntry::$1
```

coming from

```
vendor\doctrine\collections\lib\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Expr\ClosureExpressionVisitor.php
```

when trying to "return $object->$field".

The trace shows that it is caused by the above mentioned function "getTrainingProgressSinceStart()" in the line

```
return $this->getTrainingProgress()->matching($criteria);
```

For some reason the matching function doesn't seem to be recognized ors something...
I don't really know what to look for now.
Any hints are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already solved this, but I will answer it either way for reference for other people.

The method: orderBy of criteria accepts an array with the Key, being the field and the sorting order being the value, so where you have:

```
/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getTrainingProgressSinceStart()
{
    $startTime = $this->getUser()->getStart();
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->gt('entry_date', $startTime))
        ->orderBy(['entry_date', 'ASC']);
    return $this->getTrainingProgress()->matching($criteria);
}
```

It should really be ['entry_date' => 'ASC']:

```
/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getTrainingProgressSinceStart()
{
    $startTime = $this->getUser()->getStart();
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->gt('entry_date', $startTime))
        ->orderBy(['entry_date' => 'ASC']);
    return $this->getTrainingProgress()->matching($criteria);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/c23e14f69b6d2d1d1e389bc8868500efc447af7b/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Criteria.php#L152